# Ubuntu 12.04 kernel 3.2.0-24 do not sound

Tags: 12.04, sound

Before few days I install some updates to my Ubuntu 12.04.
After those updates I have not any sound.
When I use older kernel 3.2.0-23 all is OK
I use i386 version Ubuntu.

```
petat@mujlin:~$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:252: žádné zvukové karty nenalezeny...(any sound card found...)
```

but

```
petat@mujlin:~$ lspci -v
[...]
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
    Subsystem: Giga-byte Technology GA-MA770-DS3rev2.0 Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 7
    Memory at fe024000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
[...]
01:05.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 3000-3300 Series]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 3000-3300 Series]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 3
    Memory at fdffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

and

```
petat@mujlin:~$ bash alsa-info.sh --stdout
/sbin/alsactl: save_state:1580: No soundcards found...
cat: /tmp/alsa-info.VCc4whbRLa/alsactl.tmp: No such file or directory upload=true&script=true&cardinfo=
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.60
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Tue May 29 16:45:06 UTC 2012


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name:      GA-MA78GM-S2H
Product Version:    


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      i686
Processor:         athlon
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     1.0.24
Library version:    1.0.25
Utilities version:  1.0.25


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------



!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

--- no soundcards ---


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
01:05.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 3000-3300 Series]


!!Advanced information - PCI Vendor/Device/Subsystem ID's
!!--------------------------------------------------------

00:14.2 0403: 1002:4383
    Subsystem: 1458:a022
--
01:05.1 0403: 1002:960f
    Subsystem: 1002:960f


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd-atiixp-modem: index=-2
snd-intel8x0m: index=-2
snd-via82xx-modem: index=-2
snd-usb-audio: index=-2
snd-usb-caiaq: index=-2
snd-usb-ua101: index=-2
snd-usb-us122l: index=-2
snd-usb-usx2y: index=-2
snd-cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd-pcsp: index=-2
snd-usb-audio: index=-2
snd_hda_intel: model=hp-dv6
snd_hda_intel: model=hp-dv6
snd_hda_intel: model=hp-dv6
snd-hda-intel: model=eapd probe_mask=1 position_fix=1
snd_hda_intel: model=hp-dv6


!!Loaded sound module options
!!--------------------------


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw---T+ 1 root audio 116,  1 May 29 18:13 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw---T+ 1 root audio 116, 33 May 29 18:13 /dev/snd/timer


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!------------

APLAY

aplay: device_list:252: no soundcards found...

ARECORD

arecord: device_list:252: no soundcards found...

!!Amixer output
!!-------------


!!Alsactl output
!!-------------

--startcollapse--
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

Module
snd_seq_dummy
snd_hrtimer
nls_iso8859_1
nls_cp437
vfat
fat
pci_stub
vboxpci
vboxnetadp
vboxnetflt
vboxdrv
bnep
rfcomm
bluetooth
parport_pc
ppdev
binfmt_misc
vesafb
snd_hda_codec
snd_hwdep
snd_pcm
snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi
usblp
snd_seq_midi_event
fglrx
snd_seq
snd_timer
joydev
snd_seq_device
snd
soundcore
sp5100_tco
snd_page_alloc
shpchp
wmi
i2c_piix4
mac_hid
psmouse
k8temp
serio_raw
lp
parport
usbhid
hid
firewire_ohci
8139too
firewire_core
crc_itu_t
8139cp
pata_atiixp
r8169
usb_storage


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!------------------

[   13.048454] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[   14.617938] snd_hda_intel: Unknown symbol vga_default_device (err 0)
[   14.618006] snd_hda_intel: Unknown symbol vga_default_device (err 0)
[   14.618900] snd_hda_intel: Unknown symbol vga_default_device (err 0)
[   14.619085] snd_hda_intel: Unknown symbol vga_default_device (err 0)
[   14.996659] type=1400 audit(1338308035.953:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=677 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: Today I make last update and all is OK. Thanks.